Azure function crash of keyvault permissions
I have an azure function, .net 8 isolated, that is using azure keyvault. To simplify i am doing this to add it:
try {
  return builder.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(vaultUri), new DefaultAzureCredential()).Build()
} catch(Exception e){
  _log.LogError(e);
}
return builder.Build();

I saw in the logs i was getting 403 errors from azure keyvault. However the azure functions wasn't working properly and no functions appeared in overview.
When i fixed the authorization toward keyvault it worked.
But i was expecting the function app to keep running without the contents from keyvault if it failed to access it. How can i prevent the crash of the function app if something goes wrong with the credentials toward azure keyvault.
Note that it wasn't the code using configuration  properties from keyvault that was crashing. All that code have fault protection.

Try resolve something before returning the configuration with the Key Vault provider added, e.g.: var foo = builder.AddAzureKeyVault(...).Build().Get<Foo>(), where Foo is a type in your project that you'd expect would bind to something from the key vault. Then you might see some RequestFailedException with 403 error.

Use below code to handle the Key vault related exceptions in .NET 8 isolated Azure function:
Function.cs:
 [Function("Function1")]
 public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
 {
     try
     {
         string keyvault = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("keyvaulturi");

         var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyvault), new DefaultAzureCredential());
         var secretName = "secret1";
         var secretValue = client.GetSecret(secretName);

         _logger.LogInformation($"The value of {secretName} is {secretValue.Value.Value}");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         _logger.LogError("Exception occurred: \n \n"+ex);
     }
     return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
 }

Able to handle the exception thrown as below:

Response:

